# NSS hosts module to handle a wildcard subdomain

Tags: c, hosts

I'm trying to implement a NSS (Name Service Switch) module in order to customize the `hosts` database. For example, assuming the arbitrary name `domain` is known:

```sh
getent hosts subdomain.domain
```

I need this to work just like

```sh
getent hosts domain
```

I test it through a Docker container. Here is the `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns wildcard
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

And the code:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include "nss_wildcard.h"

enum nss_status _nss_wildcard_gethostbyname_r(
    const char *name,
    struct hostent *result,
    char *buffer,
    size_t buflen,
    int *errno_p,
    int *h_errno_p
) {
    char * const sep_at = strchr(name, '.');

    if (sep_at != NULL) {
        struct addrinfo hints, *res;
        int errcode;
        void *ptr = NULL;

        memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;

        errcode = getaddrinfo (sep_at + 1, NULL, &hints, &res);
        if (errcode != 0) {
            perror ("getaddrinfo");
            return -1;
        }

        strcpy(result->h_name, sep_at + 1);

        if (res) {
            inet_ntop (res->ai_family, res->ai_addr->sa_data, result->h_addr_list[0], 100);

            switch (res->ai_family) {
                case AF_INET:
                    ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
                    break;
                case AF_INET6:
                    ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
                    break;
            }
            inet_ntop (res->ai_family, ptr, result->h_addr_list[0], 100);
            printf ("IPv%d address: %s (%s)\n", res->ai_family == PF_INET6 ? 6 : 4,
                  result->h_addr_list[0], res->ai_canonname);

            result->h_addrtype = res->ai_family;

            result->h_length = sizeof(result->h_addr_list[0]);

            printf("%s\n", res->ai_canonname);
        }

        freeaddrinfo(res);
        printf("SUCCESS\n");

        return NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    printf("NOT FOUND\n");

    return NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND;
}

enum nss_status _nss_wildcard_gethostbyname2_r(
    const char *name,
    int af,
    struct hostent * result,
    char *buffer,
    size_t buflen,
    int *errno_p,
    int *h_errno_p
) {
    if (af != AF_INET) {
        *h_errno_p = NO_DATA;
        return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
    }

    return _nss_wildcard_gethostbyname_r(name, result, buffer, buflen, errno_p, h_errno_p);
}

enum nss_status _nss_wildcard_gethostbyaddr_r(
    struct in_addr *addr,
    int len,
    int af,
    struct hostent *result,
    char *buffer,
    size_t buflen,
    int *errno_p,
    int *h_errno_p
) {
    return NSS_STATUS_UNAVAIL;
}
```

The test container is bound to another container which he can reach through `webserver`. So I get that

```sh
getent hosts webserver
172.22.0.3      webserver
```

but when I add a subdomain

```sh
getent hosts test.webserver
IPv4 address: 172.22.0.3 (webserver)
webserver
SUCCESS
49.55.50.46     webserver
```

Except the last line, you can see my `printf` calls which look OK as I got the searched IPv4. Though, the last line (the real output of `getent hosts`) prints another address and I don't understand why.

Finally, when I `curl` both, I get that:

```sh
curl -s webserver
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```sh
curl -s test.webserver
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not a C expert.

P.S: If needed, I can provide a small project with a Dockerfile in order to test easily.

Comment: You seem to be converting the address to a string for the result? The addresses are the IP addresses in bytes, not the IP address as a string